# Why is running android app so slow on windows 7, pentium n3540?

Tags: performance, android-studio, android-emulator

I installed android studio 2.2 and created emulator nexus 4.

My emulator's details are:

```
Name: Nexus_4_API_23

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86_64)

Path: D:\Programs\Android\.android\avd\Nexus_4_API_23.avd

Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 23)

Skin: nexus_4

SD Card: D:\Programs\Android\.android\avd\Nexus_4_API_23.avd\sdcard.img

hw.dPad: no

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: Nexus 4

vm.heapSize: 64

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.gps: yes

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 23

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-23\google_apis\x86_64\

tag.id: google_apis

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: emulated

hw.mainKeys: no

AvdId: Nexus_4_API_23

hw.camera.front: emulated

hw.lcd.density: 320

avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 4 API 23

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.device.hash2: MD5:6930e145748b87e87d3f40cabd140a41

hw.ramSize: 512

hw.trackBall: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.cpu.ncore: 2

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google APIs

runtime.network.latency: none

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

disk.dataPartition.size: 800M

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

When I run simple app it does gradle rebuild and launches it on emulator. And it takes near 2 minutes every time I run it even when emulator is on.

In console, run ends with these messages:

```
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/gralloc_ranchu: Emulator without host-side GPU emulation detected.
```

Haxm is installed and working. Intel virtualization technology is enabled in bios.

What is wrong with my emulator options? 
Why is my android studio so slow?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. In android studio go to `Tools>Android>AVD Manager`.

Click on `edit` button of your virtual device

Next find `Graphics` option and select `Hardware - GLES 2.0`.

Now running app when emulator is on is very quick.

And in console there is no message: `Emulator without host-side GPU emulation detected.`

The best android tutorial I've found is at https://www.udacity.com/course/new-android-fundamentals--ud851
There are more free android tutorials at https://www.udacity.com/courses/android

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions for best performance:

1. Install Intel HAXM:

   https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager
2. Enable Host GPU:

   [image]

Comment: Thank you but Haxm is installed and working and there is no emulation options in android studio but only emulated performance. I tried automatic and software graphics but they make no sense